# Get the Data of any user according to ID

Tags: swift, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

so, here how can i get the data of any user according to `uid`s ?

[image]

Comment: Since you're using the uid as the documentId, also storing it in a field is redundant and not necessary. e.g. if you know the documentId (the uid in this case), you will never need to query for it on your users collection.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From your screenshot we can see that the value of the field `uid` is also used as the ID of the user's Firestore document (which is a very good approach :-))

Therefore you can simply query the document of a specific user as follows:

```
let docRef = db.collection("users").document(uid)  // We use the uid to define the Document Reference 

docRef.getDocument { (document, error) in
    if let document = document, document.exists {
        let dataDescription = document.data().map(String.init(describing:)) ?? "nil"
        print("Document data: \(dataDescription)")
    } else {
        print("Document does not exist")
    }
}
```